# how to refresh dialog in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a from in dialog. Everything works percectly, but how can I refresh the values in inputs after save data in db?

Is there a trick to refresh whole form or should I use dialog.reset() when someone hides dialog by pressing Cancel button? If it could be done only by reset() method, so how can I handle event when escape is pressed and the closing-cross (in the top-right corner)

Best regards

Comment: after the user saves do you want to clear the inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, if a user closes a dialog, I just destroy the thing and create a new one.

You can use something like this to capture when the user has closed the dialog, and clean it up:

```
myDialog.connect(myDialog, 'close', function(){myDialog.destroy();});
```

Note that the fact that you use the `connect()` method on the dialog widget means that the connect itself will also be cleaned up when the widget is destroyed.

Nice and neat :)

If you are just looking to clear the form, you can use `document.myform.reset()` in the close connect.

A more complete example:

```
showDia: function(){
    myDia = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "Public Reminder",
        content: "<center>My incredible dialog content that will change the world</center><br>"+
            "<form id='fooBarForm'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='fooName' id='fooId' value='fooValue'></input>"+
            "<select name='barName' style='margin: 3px;' id='barId'>"+
            "<option value='barOpt1'>test1</option>"+
            "<option value='barOpt2'>test2</option>"+ 
            "</select>"+
            "</form>",
        style: "width: 320px;"
    });
    myDia.connect(myDia, 'close', function(){myDia.destroy();});
    // OR you can call `reset()` on the fooBarForm instead of `myDia.destroy()`, and when 
    // you call `showDia()`, check if the dialog already exists and then just call `show()` on 
    // it
    myDia.show();
}
```

Now, one thing about this is that is does introduce a global name (myDia).  But you can easily make that a member of an object and that won't be the case.  showDia should also be a member method on an object (ie, not a global function).

Also, this is often done by using a content pane to pull in the content from a URL.

Comment: great :) but when I destroy dialog I can't use show() again. Of course its destroyed but how can I show it again? Now i just statically generate dialog in div html: <div id="external" data-dojo-type="dijit.Dialog" href="/form" style="overflow:auto; width: 365px;">

Comment: If you do want to re-use it, then you can connect to the close event as above, and clear the form at that point, or connect to the `show()` method and do it then.  If you want to re-display it and you've destroyed it, just re-create it the same way :)

Comment: hmm I understand that, but I dont know how to writte it, could You be so nice and give me a hint or a sample?

Comment: Added a more complete example

Comment: you could do as suggested and connect to the `show()` method. when the dialog opens you do an ajax call to get the latest data from the server, then set the form fields with the returned data.

Answer (score 1):

if you create the dialog through your program as new dijit.Dialog(), then when you setting the url you have to set an extra parameter as random number thus every request to server will be treated as new request.......and that is the trick..actually i have succeed this way.

Comment: it is always better to use the time stamp over the random number... like new Date().getTime();